# GoLang value not updated for returned Package variable

Tags: pointers, go

Hi I am new to go and am trying to get my head around why the Package value that is returned by the method GetPerson() is not updated when I updated the returned value. I know how i could change the method to make it work, Im more after an explanation of what is going on?

```
package main 

import "fmt"

type Person struct{
    FirstName, LastName string
    Age int
}

var p Person = Person{"Bob","Rolf",15}

func GetPerson() Person{
    return p
}

func main(){
    fmt.Println(GetPerson())
    rP := GetPerson()
    rP.Age = 40
    fmt.Println(GetPerson())
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GetPreson returns a copy of the value. Changes to the copy are not reflected in the original.

Return a pointer to the value and update through the pointer.

```
package main 

import "fmt"

type Person struct{
  FirstName, LastName string
  Age int
}

var p Person = Person{"Bob","Rolf",15}

func GetPerson() *Person{  // note *
  return &p                // note &
}

func main(){
  fmt.Println(GetPerson())
  rP := GetPerson()
  rP.Age = 40
  fmt.Println(GetPerson())
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/OTVvM13OEU)